# what is the difference between gst-omx and gst-v4l2 plugins? Which is better? Which one to use for the new jetson orin?

Tags: video, gstreamer, decode, encode, codec

I cannot understand what is the difference between gst-omx and gst-v4l2. And which one to use? Which provides better performance for video encoding and decoding H264?

Can anyone provide me more details?

Answer (score 0):

There are both API to use Hardware encoder/decoder.

Depending the encoder/decoder implementation you have on your board support package you can select gst-v4l2 or gst-omx.

I think performances on both depends on the implementation by the manufacturer. But when you develop apps using theses API you should :

- Avoid unnecessary buffers copy to preserve memory bandwidth.
- Avoid unnecessary color conversions.

Here some informations about V4L2 codecs:
https://events.static.linuxfound.org/images/stories/pdf/lceu2012_debski.pdf

Do you know which implementation is available on your BSP ?